# Converting an object to a buffer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, buffer, web-worker

#### I'm not using node, just plain Javascript in the browser

I need to efficiently send data to webworkers. I've managed to figure out how to create buffers from arrays:

```
// assume it contains integers
var numbers = new Int8Array(10); 

// works
const data = {buffer: numbers.buffer};
worker.postMessage(data, [data.buffer]);
```

But let's assume I have an object that looks like the following:

```
var myObject = {'in': [0.123,-0,521], 'out' : [1.409]};
```

How would I convert that to a buffer? I've found numerous similar questions but they seem to use *Node*, which i'm not using.

Comment: Well, one way would be to convert the object to an array, and send that. And construct an object on the other side as well. I've never done anything like this so that's all I can help with.

Comment: Maybe use TypedObjects ? And youll loose the information (the keys) so you need a certain structure e.g. in:bytes 0-3, out:bytes 4-7

Comment: @Ted that's what I thought as well, seems like a good idea

Comment: @thomas w are in and out .length variable? (makes it more complicated)

Comment: @Jonasw what do you mean exactly? They have a `.length` variable, but they are just regular arrays

Comment: @thomas w ive meant the verb *variable* , so are they always length=2 and length=1 or sth else?

Comment: @Jonasw yes always that length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a typed Array like this:

```
[obj1.in1,obj1.in2,obj1.out,obj2.in1,...]
```

With one object:

```
var arr=Int8Array.from(myObject.in.concat(myObject.out));
```

With an Array of objects:

```
var ObjArr=[obj1,obj2];
var arr=new Int8Array(ObjArr.length*3);

for(var i=0;i<ObjArr.length;i++){
  var obj=ObjArr[i];
  arr.set(obj.in.concat(obj.out),i*3);
}
```

To iterate over you could use a simple for loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length-2;i+=3){
 var in1=arr[i],in2=arr[i+1],out=arr[i+2];
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a bunch.